# Differences between To throw and To throw at?

Tags: differences, prepositions

I throw the paper to you.

I throw the paper at you.

What is the difference?
And why and how the "at" changes this meaning?

Comment: Your title should read 'difference between throw to and throw at'. What do those prepositions mean? Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: [How and why **does the "at"** change a meaning? Grammar correction] If I give it to you, I am not throwing it at you.

Comment: How about "I throw the stone to you" and "I throw the stone at you"?

Comment: If I throw something to you, you're probably expecting it.

Comment: Yes, I always check dictionaries, but I didn't get the explanations (not a native), the examples they give are not clear enough for me. I don't include those examples, as I'd like fresh examples, from your own understanding, as natives, as a first step: without being influenced, by a dictionary.

Comment: Please remove the "on hold", as the question will probably be useful for other learners. (I don't see how it's off-topic by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence means that you're *giving* the paper *to* the other person, by throwing it.

The second sentence means you're aiming for the person, like a target.

Comment: Thank you, I though that, but didn't include it in the question to be sure it exactly need that for natives.